# mysqldump error while copying database from server to another

Tags: mysql

I'm trying to copy database from one server to another like this

```
mysqldump -u<source_db_username> -p<source_db_password> -h<source_db_ip_address> source_database_name
| mysql -u<target_db_username> -p<target_db_password> -h<aws_rds_endpoint> <aws_rds_db_name>;
```

But I get

```
You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server 
version for the right syntax to use near 'mysqldump -u<source_db_username> -p<source_db_password> 
-h<source_db_ip_address> source_database_name ' at line 1
```

Comment: `mysqldump` is a shell command, you're trying to use it in `mysql`.

Answer (score 0):

I shouldn't use the database while copying I just have to refer the mysql location to use it and shouldn't use ';' at the end of the command it's working now.